# What causes deprecation warning: ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks=?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get this message when I run my feature specs:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base.raise_in_transactional_callbacks= is deprecated, has no effect and will be removed without replacement.

I am using Rails 5.0.0.rc1 and am not sure what is throwing this deprecation warning.

I had this in my `application.rb` file.  I removed it and the deprecation warning went away:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```

I'd like tips on what this deprecation warning actually means and to know what triggers this deprecation warning.

Comment: It could be from the new inheritance structure with ActiveRecord now inheriting from ApplicationRecord instead of directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base but not sure.  Can't wait to jump into rails5 once it's mainstream!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I believe this behaviour was added between 4.1 and 4.2 as a temporary solution to a problem which is no longer relevant in rails 5:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#error-handling-in-transaction-callbacks

> Currently, Active Record suppresses errors raised within
>   after_rollback or after_commit callbacks and only prints them to the
>   logs. In the next version, these errors will no longer be suppressed.
>   Instead, the errors will propagate normally just like in other Active
>   Record callbacks.
>
> When you define an after_rollback or after_commit callback, you will
>   receive a deprecation warning about this upcoming change. When you are
>   ready, you can opt into the new behavior and remove the deprecation
>   warning by adding following configuration to your
>   config/application.rb:
>
> `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true`

For clarification, as @pixelearth suggests my comment below isn't clear/prominent enough. In Rails 5 and later remove the line from `config/application.rb`:

> `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true`

Comment: I had what you mentioned, yet I still see the warning?

Comment: If you're using Rails 5 you are getting that warning because the option is set not because you don't have it. Try removing the line from your config.

Answer (score 3):

Writing this here for more visbility for @R. Hatherall's comment.

I was getting this warning when upgrading to 5 not becuase I DIDN't have the following setting in application.rb, but because I DID.

In rails 5 remove the following line from application.rb

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
```